# Script that takes hours, minutes and seconds and returns a virtual watch not working as expected

Tags: python, python-turtle

This is the script for anyone interested. Another thing I don't understand is that it only draws two out of the tree hands. Also, I think this is a very inefficient way of doing this task so any tips on how to make it more efficient are welcome.

```
import math
import turtle
h=int(input())
m=int(input())
s=int(input())
turtle.hideturtle()
f=30*h+m*0.5+s*0.0083,m*6+s*0.1,s*6
for i in f:
    hsin=math.sin(math.radians((i%360)%90))*80
    hcos=math.cos(math.radians((i%360)%90))*80
    if  i//90==0:
        turtle.setpos(hsin,hcos)
    elif  i//90==1:
        turtle.setpos(hcos,-hsin)
    elif  i//90==2:
        turtle.setpos(-hsin,-hcos)
    elif  i//90==3:
        turtle.setpos(-hcos,hsin)
    turtle.setpos(0,0)
```

I have no clue as to why it doesn't work I have started learning Python about a month ago so I am by no means an expert. I tried rewriting the `f` variable which is a list containing all the
formulas required in order to calculate how many degrees a hand needs to travel from 12 o'clock clockwise to reach our destination.

Comment: I see three hands when I run this. I recommend hardcoding your failing test case. It's unclear what numbers are being put into `input()` here. Also, I suggest using [black](https://black.vercel.app/) to format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Like @ggorlen, I see three hands when I run it.  For debugging purposes, I would make the code simpler and make the hands different from one another (e.g. hour hand shortest and fatest, the second hand longest and thinest):

```
import math
import turtle

h = turtle.numinput("Input time", "Please enter hour", minval=0, maxval=24)
m = turtle.numinput("Input Time", "Please enter minute", minval=0, maxval=59)
s = turtle.numinput("Input Time", "Please enter second", minval=0, maxval=59)

angles = s*6, m*6 + s*0.1, 30*h + m*0.5 + s*0.0083333

turtle.hideturtle()

for hand, angle in enumerate(angles, start=1):
    turtle.width(hand)

    x = math.sin(math.radians(angle % 360)) * 80/hand
    y = math.cos(math.radians(angle % 360)) * 80/hand

    turtle.setpos(x, y)
    turtle.home()

turtle.exitonclick()
```